# Force ul li ul on new line while using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

after I spent two hours trying to figure this out by myself, I feel it's the right time to ask people who actually know how to code.

**What is my situation**

I'm building a WordPress theme and I struggle to make the navigation work the way I want it. What I have in mind looks like this:
[sketch of home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXy2f.png)

Since it is WordPress menu (and because I plan to adapt the looks throughout the website), I need it to be a list. But I struggle to make the first-level items appear as headings and the second-level items as items below.

This is as far as I got:
https://jsfiddle.net/grysom/bpe924du/

I tried random stuff using flexbox properties + adding a break using :after selector with `content: "\A";` but with no luck.

Do you have an idea how to do it? Is it even possible?

Thank you in advance for your ideas!

Have a nice day

grysom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want the 2nd level list `<ul>` to be **inside** of the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      Pro veřejnost
      <ul>
         <li>Co je ergoterapie</li>
         <li>Kdo je ergoterapeut</li>
         <li>Seznam zařízení</li>
         <li>Etický kodex</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      Praxe
       <ul>
          <li>Nabídky práce</li>
         <li>Vychytávky a tipy</li>
         <li>Legislativa</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I've updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grysom/bpe924du/ but you'll need to adjust your styles a bit to differentiate the levels.

Comment: Oh well, overlooked the basics once again… Thank you for showing me. :)